# What Are The Most Effective Clicks For The Button?

Tags: java, android

What are the most effective button clicks in Android Actually I have several activities and every activity has a button and its function sends sending information to another activity But I do not know the real reason behind what happens But the transmitter command in some buttons stopped responding like I did not press anything on the screen Traced error handler did not show me an error message but the button does not respond You have tried this code

```
private int quantity1 =1;

 img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (quantity1 == 100) {
                Snackbar.make( view,getString( R.string.add_one ),Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                return;
            }
            quantity1 = quantity1 + 1;
            displayQuantity( quantity1 );
        }
    });

public void primo (View view){
textPr = "";
textPr += "(" + quantity1 + ")" + "   " + getString( R.string.primo_string );

pricePr = quantity1 * 500 ;

Intent primo = new Intent(this, Sandwish.class);
primo.putExtra( REG_INT_TAG_PRIMO, pricePr);
primo.putExtra( REG_NAME_TAG_PRIMO, textPr );
setResult(RESULT_OK, primo);
finish();
```

}

And this too,

```
b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btns);

b1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        textBl = "";
        textBl += "(" + quantity1 + ")" + "   " + getString( R.string.blanche_string );

        priceBl = quantity1 * 500 ;

            Intent blanche = new Intent();
            blanche.putExtra( REG_INT_TAG, priceBl);
            blanche.putExtra( REG_NAME_TAG,textBl );
            setResult(RESULT_OK,blanche);
            finish();
        }
});
```

xml file

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnsPr"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:onClick="primo"
        android:text="@string/send_to_shopping_basket"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:fontFamily="casual"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        />
```

Comment: why are you using setResult() method?

Comment: When UI stops responding you are doing time consuming work in UI thread such as network or file i/o thus i guess your code problem is some where else , find where you are doing time consuming work in UI thread and move it to background thread

Comment: Yes and the code itself works successfully with other activities but stops in some of them and I do not know why

Comment: @WIZARD The user interface does not stop, but the button does not respond to it, and I did not put it when you pressed it

Comment: maybe in some of `onCreate` of activities you are doing time consuming work on UI thread

Comment: The application contains several activities for each activity. The commands inside are very simple only if the user dials the quantity number in excess of one number
Pressing the button  to send the number of the quantity that the user has requested with a simple text inserted in the string file
This code is the same in all activities
He is now working with only one activity and the rest is not responding to them

Comment: So I changed the order of the activity and put a textView to display the value requested by the user in the same activtion to be sure if the error in the order of the transmitter or in the reception
But the problem lies in the activity itself that the button does not respond
like I did not put orders for him to implement his definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        textBl = "";
        textBl += "(" + quantity1 + ")" + "   " + getString( R.string.blanche_string );

        priceBl = quantity1 * 500 ;

            Intent blanche = new Intent();
            blanche.putExtra( REG_INT_TAG, priceBl);
            blanche.putExtra( REG_NAME_TAG,textBl );
            setResult(RESULT_OK,blanche);
            finish();
        }
});
```

your code means that one activity has started this activity with `startActivityForResult` then you set result and finish this activity on first activity override `onActivityResult` and use the result

Comment: @R.katiana did you have start this activity whit `startActivityForResult` ?

Comment: @R.katiana when you finish activity on button click does activity closes? if it will be closed it means your `onClick` is called correctly

Comment: Yes, do not close, and i try this thing too, and the button does not respond

Comment: try rebuild project maybe button ids is out of sync or check the id you are using is correct button id

Comment: i transcript was replaced code of send by the text command (textView.setText(textBl)) but it did not work